# How to add default value 0000-00-00 to date datatype in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I previously changed data type of my column by using below command but now I want to add default value like 0000-00-00 for the same column, can any one help me?

alter table table name  alter column name type date using(column name::date)

Comment: That is an invalid date and Postgres won't let you store invalid DATE values. You can't use that as a default value. If you want to indicate that there is no value use `null` - that's what it is for. Or use `-infinity` if you need a non-null value that lies before all possible DATE values.

Comment: If you just want the ability to store "unknown date" in the column, mark it as NULLable. I suspect you're trying to mimic MySQL's behaviour of using `0000-00-00` as a placeholder, but I can't think of any good reason to do so.

Comment: There is no such date as `0000-00-00`. There is no year `0` nor month `0` nor day `0`. The smallest possible is `0001-01-01`.

Comment: If I'm trying to skip that column it is showing ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Comment: Ah, I think we have an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your actual problem is with how you're inserting data, not with the table definition. Trying to pass an empty string as a value is *not* the same as skipping the column, so that error suggests you have written the wrong SQL.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to insert values from html page and the date column is not mandatory, so it is passing empty string when ever I skip that column.

Comment: @SampathSam Right, so that's your bug: you shouldn't pass an empty string when you have no value. Setting a default on the column won't help, because as far as the database is concerned, you *are* passing a value, the empty string. You need to change the code that generates the SQL to specify `NULL` when you don't have a value.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks a lot, I will change my logic.

Answer (score 8):

You have an issue if the column is a `date` because `0000-00-00` is not a valid date.  The syntax for setting the default is:

```
 alter table t alter column col set default '0001-01-01';
```

However, you need a valid date for that.  I would recommend just using `NULL` if that works for your application.

Comment: For completeness, to allow nulls in a column that currently blocks them, the syntax is `alter table t alter column col drop not null`

Comment: Is it possible to insert NULL instead of '0001-01-01'

Comment: If all your dates are >= 1970, you could also use `default to_timestamp(0)`

Comment: Without ::date the default value wasn't added in my case. ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN col SET DEFAULT '0001-01-01'::date;